# .NET 5 - SWAGGER.json

Tags: .net, swagger, .net-5

I've generated a swagger.json file for my public apis. It works really nice with the following code:

**In Startup - Configure Services**

```
            //Register Swagger Options as Dependency Injection
        services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
        
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            // add a custom operation filter which sets default values
            //options.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();

            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

        });
```

**In Startup - Configure**

```
app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.InjectStylesheet("../css/customize-swagger-ui.css");
            c.InjectJavascript("../js/customize-swagger-ui.js");
            // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
            foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());

            }

        });
```

My problem is, that i would like to add the name of the method behind the API-Request. Otherwise a tool like NSWAG for Client-Code-Generation creates a lot of different methods which are called APIRoute1, APIRoute2, APIRoute3, ...

Here is a json-snippet of the swagger generated file:

```
"paths": {
"/api/v1/Order": {
  "post": {
    "tags": [
      "Order"
    ],
    "summary": "Creates a new Order if no order currently exists",
    "requestBody": {
      "description": "",
      "content": {
        "application/json": {
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateOrderModel"
          }
        },
        "text/json": {
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateOrderModel"
          }
        },
        "application/*+json": {
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateOrderModel"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success"
      }
    }
  }
},
"/api/v1/Order/{orderNumber}": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "Order"
    ],
    "summary": "Reads a given Order if exists",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "orderNumber",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "Order Number",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        }
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/OrderDTO"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "Bad Request",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "404": {
        "description": "Not Found",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

APIRoute is only a placeholder as an example. The methods behinde APIRouteX are implemented with the same route but the http variable is different like (POST, DELETE, PUT). So its really hard to read the client-code generated code.

Is it possible to add the "Method-Name" behind the route to the swagger.json file?

**SWAGGER Configure Options**

```
    /// <summary>
/// Configures the Swagger Options like Titel, Contact Informations etc
/// </summary>
public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions : IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
{
    readonly IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor which adds ApiVersionDescription by Dependency Injection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="provider">API Version Description Provider</param>
    public ConfigureSwaggerOptions(IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider) => this.provider = provider;

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a seperate Swagger Document for each API Version
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options">Swagger Generic Options</param>
    public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName, CreateInfoForApiVersion(description.ApiVersion.ToString(), description.IsDeprecated));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates Header Informations for API
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="description">ApiVersionDescription</param>
    /// <returns>Api Info</returns>
    static OpenApiInfo CreateInfoForApiVersion(string version, bool isDeprecated)
    {
        var info = new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = "Rüstkontrolle API",
            Version = version,
            Description = "Service Dokumentation für das AddOn Rüstkontrolle im SICK Werkerportal",
            Contact = new OpenApiContact() { Name = "Lukas Adler", Email = "lukas.adler@sick.de" },
            License = new OpenApiLicense() { Name = "",}
        };

        if (isDeprecated)
        {
            info.Description += "API version is deprecated.";
        }
        return info;
    }
}
```

**Swagger Default Values**

```
    /// <summary>
/// Swagger Operation Filter
/// </summary>
public class SwaggerDefaultValues : IOperationFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Applies Operations and OperationsFilterContext on API Descriptions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation">Operation</param>
    /// <param name="context">OperationFilterContext</param>
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {

        var apiDescription = context.ApiDescription;

        if (operation.Parameters == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var parameter in operation.Parameters)
        {
            var description = apiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.First(p => p.Name == parameter.Name);

            if (parameter.Description == null)
            {
                parameter.Description = description.ModelMetadata?.Description;
            }

            parameter.Required |= description.IsRequired;
        }
    }
}
```

**NSWAG Konfiguration**

```
    {
  "runtime": "NetCore21",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "fromDocument": "HERE IS NORMALLY MY API DESCRIPTION",
      "url": "https://localhost:44314/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
      "output": null,
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "clientBaseClass": null,
      "configurationClass": null,
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": false,
      "clientBaseInterface": null,
      "injectHttpClient": true,
      "disposeHttpClient": true,
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "generateExceptionClasses": true,
      "exceptionClass": "ApiException",
      "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
      "useHttpClientCreationMethod": false,
      "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
      "useHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod": false,
      "useBaseUrl": true,
      "generateBaseUrlProperty": true,
      "generateSyncMethods": false,
      "generatePrepareRequestAndProcessResponseAsAsyncMethods": false,
      "exposeJsonSerializerSettings": false,
      "clientClassAccessModifier": "public",
      "typeAccessModifier": "public",
      "generateContractsOutput": false,
      "contractsNamespace": null,
      "contractsOutputFilePath": null,
      "parameterDateTimeFormat": "s",
      "parameterDateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "generateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod": true,
      "useRequestAndResponseSerializationSettings": false,
      "serializeTypeInformation": false,
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "className": "{controller}Client",
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId",
      "additionalNamespaceUsages": [],
      "additionalContractNamespaceUsages": [],
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "generateJsonMethods": false,
      "enforceFlagEnums": false,
      "parameterArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable",
      "parameterDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "responseArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "responseDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "namespace": "MyNamespace",
      "requiredPropertiesMustBeDefined": true,
      "dateType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "jsonConverters": null,
      "anyType": "object",
      "dateTimeType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "timeType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "timeSpanType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "arrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "arrayInstanceType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "dictionaryInstanceType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "arrayBaseType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryBaseType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "classStyle": "Poco",
      "jsonLibrary": "NewtonsoftJson",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "generateDataAnnotations": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateImmutableArrayProperties": false,
      "generateImmutableDictionaryProperties": false,
      "jsonSerializerSettingsTransformationMethod": null,
      "inlineNamedArrays": false,
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedTuples": true,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": false,
      "generateNullableReferenceTypes": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
      "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": null,
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually, NSwag use the route to generate method's name. In your case two method `Order` with different parameter. Can you share your NSwag configuration?

Comment: @vernou i've added the reqeuested informations. In the implementation the two methods of order has different names like "createOrder" and "readOrder"

Comment: I wasn"t clear. Can you share the NSwag (client code generation) settings?

Comment: @vernou please take a look again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SwaggerGenOptions.CustomOperationIds` to specify your own custom operation Ids. E.g. I use the following setting:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomOperationIds(x => ${x.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"]}_{x.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"]}");
});
```

This creates operation Ids like `Client_GetDetail` that you can configure NSWAG to create client APIs like `clientApi.getDetail()`.

PS You are using [Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) in your project, if you use [NSwag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) then it should set it by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the NSWag settings, `operationGenerationMode` is set to `MultipleClientsFromOperationId` :

> From the first operation tag and operation ID (operation name = operation ID, client name = first operation tag).

But the OpenAPI contract (swagger.json file in your case) don't specify operation's id.

I see two solution, choose a other value to `operationGenerationMode` or specify operation's id.

The other `operationGenerationMode` values [are](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/CodeGeneration/OperationGenerationMode.cs) :

```cs
public enum OperationGenerationMode
{
    /// <summary>Multiple clients from the Swagger operation ID in the form '{controller}_{action}'.</summary>
    MultipleClientsFromOperationId,

    /// <summary>From path segments (operation name = last segment, client name = second to last segment).</summary>
    MultipleClientsFromPathSegments,

    /// <summary>From the first operation tag and path segments (operation name = last segment, client name = first operation tag).</summary>
    MultipleClientsFromFirstTagAndPathSegments,

    /// <summary>From the first operation tag and operation ID (operation name = operation ID, client name = first operation tag).</summary>
    MultipleClientsFromFirstTagAndOperationId,

    /// <summary>From the Swagger operation ID.</summary>
    SingleClientFromOperationId,

    /// <summary>From path segments suffixed by HTTP operation name</summary>
    SingleClientFromPathSegments,
}
```

If you prefer specify the operation's id, you can set the name in `Http[Get|Put|...]Attribute` :

```cs
[HttpGet(Name = "SpecifiedOperationId")]
public IActionResult Get()
```